# How can i get mongodb execute result without objectid?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin

I'm tring to parse a mongodb execute result to my data class. But the result have a field '_id' and my data class don't have this field. I can't change this data class due to i have to create a instance in other place.

Is there a way can let kotlin.serialization skip _id field? Or there is a easier way to done this?

```kotlin
val lookup = users.find(Filters.eq("username", req.username)).filter(Filters.eq("password", sha256(req.password))).iterator().tryNext()
if(lookup != null) {
    val usr = Json.decodeFromString<UserStorage>(lookup.toJson()) // kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Unexpected JSON token at offset 2: Encountered an unknown key '_id'
    // some other code
    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK)
} else {
    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, Json.encodeToString(SRequestFailedResponse("Error", "Invalid credentials. Invalid username or password.", "Wrong username/password")))
}
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I am not certain this will help, but consider using projections and exclude the _id field.  By the way, your model classes should support _id in some fashion.  If not, you are going to have other difficulties.  The _id acts as the primary key for the records.

Comment: I agree with @barrypicker that you must have `_id` in your model class. Projections may help or you may even try writing your own deserializer that can exclude the `_id` field.

Answer (score 0):

Projection can fix your problem:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "username": req.username,
      "password": sha256(req.password)
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```